# What is a quick way to find the reverse complement in bash

Tags: sequence-analysis, phylogenetics, bash

I have a DNA sequence for which I would like to quickly find the reverse complement. Is there a quick way of doing this on the bash command line using only GNU tools?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to [Manu Tamminen](http://manutamminen.info/posts/unix_tricks/) for this solution:

```
echo ACCTTGAAA | tr ACGTacgt TGCAtgca | rev
```

Comment: And if I want to put it into a variable instead of echo it?

Comment: I would enclose the code in $() and assign to a variable assuming you are using a recent version of bash.

Comment: that works thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Reverse complement FASTA/Q:

```
seqtk seq -r in.fa > out.fa
```

https://github.com/lh3/seqtk

Answer (score 2):

You may either install the emboss package (http://emboss.sourceforge.net/download/) and use the revseq program.
It contains many useful command-line programs such as the pairwise alignment tool needle.